# admin view test not failing

Tags: python, django, django-testing

I am trying to test the admin changelist views if they work properly. This is the code that I use:

```
from django.test import Client
from django.test import TestCase
class TestAdminViews(TestCase):
    def test_admin(self, user = None, name = None):
        client=Client()
        if user is None:
            password = "test"
            user = User.objects.create_superuser('testadmin', 'test@test.com', password)       
        success=client.login(username = user.username, password = password)
        self.assertTrue(success, "Login Failed!")
        app="messwertdb"
        mymodels=["messrun","messung"]
        for model in mymodels:
            response = client.get(reverse('admin:%s_%s_changelist'% (app, model)))
            print reverse('admin:%s_%s_changelist'% (app, model)), response.status_code, response.content.count("exception")#test line                 self.assertEqual(response.status_code,200,"Response not ok!")
```

I have broken one of the views by trying to display a nonexisting attribute. So if I try to get it in the browser I get an AttributeError (which results in a 500 response if DEBUG=False). However, in my test I always get a 200 response -meaning no testfailures. If I enter the exact same code in the shell I get the proper Error. In the test case it seems to return an empty but otherwise correct changelist.

The broken admin.py:

```
class MessRunAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display=('type','date','path','failure')
    def failure(self, obj):
          return obj.nonexisting #this does not exist
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a simple mistake: I forgot to load the fixture so the testdatabase was empty and as it did not try to show any instance it did not call the failing attribute. And in the shell it was using the deployment database which was not empty.

So I changed it to the following code, which now fails:

```
class TestAdminViews(TestCase):
    fixtures= ["messwertdb.yaml"]
    def test_admin(self, user = None, name = None):
        .......
```